# How to load a javascript file containing ajax call asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have a JavaScript file named JScript.js this file contain a function below i.e a ajax call to a dot-net page

```
alert('jscript.js called');

function AddTag() {
var htag = document.getElementById("hdntag").value.split('|');
var texttag = document.getElementById("taginput").value;

for (i = 1; i < htag.length; i++) {
    var onetag = htag[i].split(',');

    if (onetag[0] == texttag) {
        alert("Already Exist!!!");
        return false;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax
                           ({
                               type: "POST",
                               url: "Checked.aspx/AddTag",
                               data: "{'TagName': '" + $('#taginput').val() + "'}",
                               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                               dataType: "json",
                               async: true,
                               cache: false,
                               success: function (msg) {
                                   document.getElementById("hdntag").value += '|' + texttag + ',' + msg.d;
                                   Makeedittabletaghtml();
                               }
                           })
});
document.getElementById("taginput").value = "";
```

}

i am trying to load this JavaScript file into a page asynchronously but I only get the alert i.e *' jscript.js called '* but the function does not execute below is the code to load the JavaScript  file asynchronously

```
 (function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script');
    dsq.type = 'text/javascript';
    dsq.src = 'JScript.js';
    dsq.async = true;
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
```

But when i include the file into the page it runs and execute fine

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JScript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) jQuery function to do this:

```
$.getScript("JScript.js", function(){
   alert("Script loaded and executed.");
   // here you can use anything you defined in the loaded script
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Farhan Ahmad already answered it, anyways, document.ready fires only when you load the page and dom gets ready, so first of all make your `JScript.js` as follows

```
alert('jscript.js called');

function AddTag() {...}

function myReadyFunc(){
    $.ajax({
    ...
    ...
    });
}
```

and then use `$.getScript` to load the file and call your `myReadyFunc()` which will call `ajax`

```
$.getScript("JScript.js", function(){
    alert("Script loaded and executed.");
    myReadyFunc();
});
```

**Reference:** [**Here.**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)